# Corona build for android hangs

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have created a game in corona labs it works great when i run it on corona simulator but when i build it with android and run it on some android device it hangs on some levels and behave silly. So how can i debug it or any other suggestion why i am facing such problem.

Comment: Could You please provide some more information. Including but not limited to Corona SDK version, code sample, expected and experienced behavior...

Answer (score 0):

When you have the error "it works in the sim but not the device", the first conclusion is that you are trying to access a file using the wrong case in the file name.  The simulator is not case sensitive, the devices are.  However, that's just an educated guess.  Your best bet is to look at your device's console log and look for warnings or errors as to what's happening.

If you need to know how to do that, please read the Corona Labs basic debugging tutorial here:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/09/tutorial-basic-debugging/